# Express 4.0, "zero or more" parameters in get path not working

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using the express 4.0 framework for node.js

I have a simple server defined as follows

```
require('express')().get('/:path*', (req, res) => res.send(req.params.path)).listen(8082);
```

If submit a get request to "localhost:8082/a/b/c", it should return

```
a/b/c
```

but instead it returns

```
a
```

I'm following the * syntax from this [guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#zero-or-more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express 4.0 use old version of `path-to-regexp` : 0.1.7. Now version is 1.2.1 If you update this module you will receive your expect