# Npm update a dependency of a dependency in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am currently using express 4.0, which uses the node module "path-to-regexp"

path-to-regexp 0.1.7 doesn't allow [zero or more path parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34586057/2746872)

I want to upgrade path-to-regexp within express to version 1.2.1

Npm update has a depth paramater shown in the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update), but I don't want to update all of express' dependencies, just path-to-regexp.

I would also prefer to do it without forking express, and without manually altering express' package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
 cd node_modules/express
 npm install path-to-regexp@1.2.1
```

Comment: Guess he will also need to run `npm shrinkwrap` to make sure that `path-to-regexp 1.2.1` is installed when he actually deploys his code to the server, assuming he is not tracking `node_modules` in a scm.