# how can i update npm package dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, svg

I have installed an npm package `react-native-cool-speedometer` and it has it own dependency `react-native-svg` I am also using `react-native-svg` in my project but there is an dependency  conflict. react-native-cool-speedometer is using `react-native-svg@12.1.0` and I am using `react-native-svg@13.8.0`.  this package version has some issue and I want to update it dependency to latest package version 13.8.0.

what I have try. I have tried to downgrade react-native-svg@12.1.0 but its not worked because it has issue.

`Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGSvgView, js engine: hermes`

I navigate to react-native-speedo-meter directory and tried to update the package with npm update react-native-svg but this has installed all other npm dependencies and but project could not be loaded. it stuck on white screen.

I have also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724635/npm-update-dependencies-of-dependencies) question but it does not help.

Comment: You may override the dependency, this question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)